# How do we add Unit Tests for Javascript hasOwnProperty() function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to add Unit Testing for this function:

```
var advance = function (des, source) {
        for (var p in source) {
            if (source.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
                des[p] = source[p];
            }
        }
        return des;
};
```

How do we check `hasOwnProperty()` method in Jasmine?

Edit:
**Possible solution**

```
var des;
var source;
beforeEach(function () {
    des = {};
    source = {
        p: 'value',
        p1: 'value1'
    };
});

beforeAll(function () {
    advance(des, source);
});

it('should has a property with the name of the argument', function () {
    expect(source).toEqual(jasmine.objectContaining({
        p: 'value'
    }));
    expect(source).not.toEqual(jasmine.objectContaining({
        p2: 'value2'
    }));
});
```

Someone, please suggest any better solution.

Comment: A better solution to what? What is your current unit test?

Comment: And dont do cross tagging. Java != JavaScript!

Comment: What _better_ solution? You did not provide your own attempt.

Comment: I have updated the question. Please take a look.

Comment: source = {p:'value, p1:'value1'};
var result = Object.keys(source).indexOf('p') != -1 // true
expect(result).toBeTruthy();

Comment: There's a typo in `advance()`: `des` vs. `dest` (beware of accidently sharing variables in the global namespace).

Comment: @try-catch-finally thanks for pointing it out. missed it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) returns true if the specified property name is only part of the object itself, not it's prototype chain.

Thus you can "simulate" such an object by creating a property on the prototype like this:

```
function Foo() {
    // own properties of "src"
    this.a = 1;
    this.b = 2;
}
// not own property of "src"
Foo.prototype.c = 1;
src = new Foo();
```

You test might look like this:

```
describe("hasOwnProperty", function() {
    var dest, src;

    beforeEach(function() {
        dest = { };

        function Foo() {
            this.a = 1;
            this.b = 2;
        }
        Foo.prototype.c = 3;
        src = new Foo();

        advance(dest, src);
    });

    it("should not pick non-own properties", function() {
        expect(dest.c).not.toBeDefined();
    });

    it("should pick own property", function() {
        expect(dest.a).toBe(1);
        expect(dest.b).toBe(2);
    });
});
```

This would fail the test:

```
function Foo() {
    this.a = 1;
    this.b = 2;
    // Own property - spec demands this to be undefined
    this.c = 3;
}
// Defined (above) as own property instead
// Foo.prototype.c = 3;
src = new Foo();
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation :)